# How to make dull and sparse text bolder?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Text on my image is dull and sparse in some places. How can I make it bolder and how can I join sparse regions on letter? (red circles on the second image)

[image: Text is dull and sparse. Some regions are not connected]

[image]

Comment: You can try to read about/use Canny filter, hope it will help [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)